# OrbitControls.js -- handleMouseMoveRotate is not a function

Tags: three.js

I am trying to have my camera pan around a skybox using mouse movement. I am using three.js and OrbitControls.js. Please take a look at my code snippets below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=UTF-8 />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>

  <script type="module">

  import * as THREE from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.module.js';

  import { DRACOLoader } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js';
  import { OrbitControls } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

        let scene, camera, renderer;
        function init() {
          scene = new THREE.Scene();
          camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,45,30000);
          camera.position.set(-900,-200,-900);
          renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
          renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
          document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
          let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
          controls.dispose();
          controls.update();

          document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
// Manually fire the event in OrbitControls
controls.handleMouseMoveRotate(event);
}

function animate() {
requestAnimationFrame( animate );
render();
}

function render() {
controls.update();
camera.lookAt( scene.position );
renderer.render( scene, camera );
}


          let materialArray = [];
          let texture_ft = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'front.png');
          let texture_bk = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'back.png');
          let texture_up = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'up.png');
          let texture_dn = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'down.png');
          let texture_rt = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'right.png');
          let texture_lf = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'left.png');

          materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_ft }));
          materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_bk }));
          materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_up }));
          materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_dn }));
          materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_rt }));
          materialArray.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture_lf }));

          for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++)
             materialArray[i].side = THREE.BackSide;
          let skyboxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10000, 10000, 10000);
          let skybox = new THREE.Mesh( skyboxGeo, materialArray );
          scene.add( skybox );
          animate();
        }
        function animate() {
          renderer.render(scene,camera);
          requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }
        init();
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have updated OrbitControl.js as such:

```html
        this.handleMouseMoveRotate = function ( event ) {

            rotateEnd.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

            rotateDelta.subVectors( rotateEnd, rotateStart ).multiplyScalar( scope.rotateSpeed );

            const element = scope.domElement;

            rotateLeft( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x / element.clientHeight ); // yes, height

            rotateUp( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.y / element.clientHeight );

            rotateStart.copy( rotateEnd );

            scope.update();

        }
```

However, I am receiving the error:

`236(index):36 Uncaught TypeError: controls.handleMouseMoveRotate is not a function at HTMLDocument.onDocumentMouseMove ((index):36:10)`

I know mouse movement is being detected as I see it firing as I move across the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I've updated the index.html file to point to a local copy of OrbitControls (with the edit I made)
You're right, I forgot to change that back to a local version. However, now I receive:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Javascript scoping. You're declaring `controls` inside of `init()`, so it's not available inside `onDocumentMouseMove()`.

```js
let scene;

function init() {
    let controls = new OrbitControls();
    scene = new Scene();
}

function onDocumentMouseMove() {
    // Controls does not exist here
    controls.dosomething();

    // But scene does exist
    scene.add(xxyyzz);
}
```

Just declare the variable up one level to increase its scope, like you do with `scene, camera, renderer`. Then it should be accessible within your functions.

Comment: Hm, that did not seem to get it to work. I moved all of this outside of function init():

```scene = new THREE.Scene();
          camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(55,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,45,30000);
          camera.position.set(-900,-200,-900);
          renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
          renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
          document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
          let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
          controls.dispose();
          controls.update();```

Comment: @Matthew Then it must be an issue with how you created the `this.handleMouseMoveRotate` function, because you're importing OrbitControls from a remote address, it's not possible to modify the remote file.

Comment: Check updated comments